# PERL: splitting and storing in hash and printing

Tags: regex, perl, split, hash

I have a 2.5GB file and want to store the contents into a hash.
The input file is somewhat like this:

Report.txt

```
chain_name    number    classification    description

chain_name    number    classification    description

chain_name    number    classification    description

chain_name    number    classification    description
```

and so on .......

This is the code I have written for this:

```
open (my $rept, "< report.txt");
open (o_f, "> output.txt");
my %hash;
while ( my $line1 = <$report_fh>)
{
  chomp $line1;
  (my $chain, my $number, my $classification , my $description) = split / {2,}/, $line1;
  #print o_f ("$chain-------->$description\n");  # for checking whether splitting took place successfully, this works perfectly.
  $hash{$chain} = $description;
}   

# for printing the hash values 
while ( my ($k,$v) = each %hash ) 
{
  print o_f (" $k ===> $v\n");
}
```

The hash printed is all jumbled up (not in the same order as how it is in the input file) and not all the lines are being printed while I am trying to print the hash.

I have been banging my head figuring this out for hours, need help with this.

Comment: The ordering of hash keys has never been guaranteed. Your hash is just doing what Perl hashes do.

Comment: ok i agree that hash keys ordering isnt guaranteed, but why it doesn't prints all the contents in the hash when i want them to be printed?

Comment: Are you trying to print every line of the input file, or just the last description for each chain?

Comment: all the chains  and their description

Comment: Then you don't want a hash. See my answer for an easy solution.

Comment: i will be the needing values for further calculations that why i am storing in the hash as keys and values.

Comment: That would have been helpful to know, as I have not perfected my mind-reading abilities yet. You still don't want a hash, though. Also, as someone else pointed out, you probably don't want to be storing GB of data in memory. Good luck.

Comment: If it doesn't print all the line, maybe you should change your split pattern. And  can you paste the missing line?

Answer (score 4):

hashes are *explicitly* unordered. Their output order is random-ish. That's by design - any time you're relying on hash ordering, then you're doing something nasty. It did get a bit worse recently (e.g. more obvious that your code was wrong). [Algorithmic Complexity attacks](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsec.html#Algorithmic-Complexity-Attacks) so the effect is more noticeable as of Perl 5.18.  But this hasn't changed the underlying problem that hashes aren't ordered, and shouldn't be assumed to be.

If you need *ordered* data, this is why we have arrays. You can either:

- push your key into an array to maintain 'file order'.
- use `sort` to order the keys for output.

So in your code, you might do:

```
$hash{$chain} = $description;
push ( @order, $chain );
```

And then to print:

```
foreach my $key ( @order ) { 
   print "$key => $hash{$key}\n";
}
```

Or alternatively:

```
foreach my $key ( sort keys %hash ) { 
    print "$key => $hash{$key}\n"; 
}
```

It may also be worth looking at [`slices`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices) of hashes - which let you extract a specific sequence of values.

NB: `%hash` is a nasty name for a variable. Call it something descriptive. Trust me on this, there's nothing worse than trying to debug code where variables are like that. I would suggest:

```
my %description_of;
```

So then you can write:

```
$description_of{$chain} = $description;
```

Comment: Upvoted for a great answer, even though I don't think it answers the OP's question. Unfortunately, I don't think the OP knows what his/her question is, so answering it correctly would prove to be impossible.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
cat report.txt | perl -F'\x20{2,}' -nale 'print $F[0]," ===> ", $F[-1]' > output.txt
```

\x20 is SPACE, `-Fpattern`, you can't use literal whitespace in the pattern.

If some line still doesn't in output.txt, you should show us more information about report.txt.

Storing 2.5G data in a hash is too bad.

Answer (score 0):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my %hashStore = (); my $cnt = '1';
my $addarry = '1'; my ($iniCnt,@twodimarray,$rings) = "";
while(<DATA>)
{
    my $line = $_; my ($one, $two,$three,$four) = "";
    if($line!~m/^$/)
    {
        $line=~s/^/$cnt\t/; my $nwline = $line;  my $i = '0';
        if($nwline=~m/^([^\t]+)\t([^\t]+)\t([^\t]+)\t([^\t]+)\t([^\t]+)/g)
        {
            $twodimarray[$addarry][$i] = $1;
            $i++;
            $twodimarray[$addarry][$i] = $2;
            $i++;
            $twodimarray[$addarry][$i] = $4;
            $i++;
            $rings = $twodimarray[$addarry];
        }
        $cnt++;

        my $keys = $rings->[0];
        my $vals = $rings->[1];
        my $last = $rings->[2];

        $hashStore{$keys}{$vals} = $last;

        #$nwline=~s## my $fulcnt=$&; my $chain=$1; my $desp=$4; chomp($chain); chomp($desp); $hashStore{$chain}=$desp; ($fulcnt); #eg;
    }
}

print Dumper \%hashStore;

__DATA__
chain_name  number1 classification1 description1

chain_name  number2 classification2 description2

chain_name  number3 classification3 description3

chain_name  number4 classification4 description4
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to store anything in memory here. Go straight from the old file to the new one.

```
open(my $old, '<', 'report.txt') or die $!;
open(my $new, '>', 'output.txt') or die $!;

while (<$old>) {
    chomp;
    my @parts = split(/\s+/);
    print $new "$parts[0] ===> $parts[3]\n";
}

close($old);
close($new);
```